# Swagger UI gives me this error message: Unable to infer base url

Tags: java, spring, swagger, swagger-ui, springfox

What can I do to get rid of this error message I see whenever I try to open my Swagger UI documentation on localhost:

> Unable to infer base url. This is common when using dynamic servlet registration or when the API is behind an API Gateway.

[screenshot of the error dialog](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V2ENR.png)

Comment: What is the version of the swagger and how did you bootstrapped it ?

Comment: Please check the [existing Q&As](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22unable+to+infer+base+url%22) about the "unable to infer base URL" error and see if any of the proposed solutions help.

Answer (score 0):

The error message "Unable to infer base url" often shows a failure of the Swagger UI to locate the API documentation automatically. This may occur when utilising dynamic servlet registration or when the API is protected by an API Gateway.
You can manually input the base url for the API documentation in the field provided to fix this error, such as http://localhost:8080/swagger-ui.html, or if the API is protected by an API Gateway, you can enter the right URL for the API Gateway.